# Why won't python find my value inside my dictionary using `in`

Tags: python, dictionary

## Python can't find my value

I have a python script take my data out of my MySQL database and convert that into a python dictionary. Im trying to find my session token inside of that python dictionary using the `in` keyword but for some reason its not working.

I tried using this python function to see if maybe there different strings with a weird format or character at the end but that doesnt work:

The function:

```py
def difference(string1, string2):
      # Split both strings into list items
  string1 = string1.split()
  string2 = string2.split()

  A = set(string1) # Store all string1 list items in set A
  B = set(string2) # Store all string2 list items in set B
 
  str_diff = A.symmetric_difference(B)
  isEmpty = (len(str_diff) == 0)
 
  if isEmpty:
    print("No Difference. Both Strings Are Same")
  else:
    print("The Difference Between Two Strings: ")
    print(str_diff)
  
  print('The programs runs successfully.')
```

### Code

Here is the code. (This is just a snippet and the encryption keys will be changed on launch.)

```py
try:
            import Debug
            Debug.difference(token, USERS['danielcaminero@plairstudio.com']['session'])
            print(token)
            print(USERS['danielcaminero@plairstudio.com']['session'])
            print(USERS)
            # check if user exists
            if token not in USERS:
                print("Doesnt work :(")
                raise Exception('Invalid token')

        except:
            
            return {'message': 'Invalid token'}, 401
```

### Output

```
No Difference. Both Strings Are Same
The programs runs successfully.
2681bd95970590adcd5950a3f7c90ef7
2681bd95970590adcd5950a3f7c90ef7
{'danielcaminero@plairstudio.com': {'password': '44b4cedfad79d8e47d1430b4da4198f72162dbc0d49452d8dc968546e1b48f14', 'role': '1', 'id': 1, 'session': '2681bd95970590adcd5950a3f7c90ef7'}}
Doesnt work :(
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2023 14:00:52] "GET /protected HTTP/1.1" 401 -
```

### What I need

Please just either tell me whats possibly wrong or how do I make this code work with the dictionary structure I have because some parts of my program rely on it.

Comment: `for key in USERS: print(key)`. Did you try this basic debugging approach first?

Comment: I did and it only printed my email as a string.

Comment: You have a nested dictionary and you've just assumed that it's going to iterate/print nested keys. It won't

Comment: Then you can't assume that `in` is going to work on the top level of your nested structure. `in` does not recurse all the nested keys and values of the object you've given it.

Comment: How do you suggest I fix it?

Comment: By comparing with the inner dictionary that actually contains the value you're expecting

Comment: See my thing is there’s going to be many values in production

Comment: What's abnormal about this case?

Comment: So I can’t just hard code my email in as the nested value if that makes sense

Comment: Then don't hard-code it. You've given a really high-level overview of what's going on here and I don't think I have a reasonable answer. The very fact that you're talking about mysql but not using _any_ SQL here, and then going through set difference.... This setup just isn't close to what you would do in production from what I can see

Comment: `for u in users:` / `if u['session'] == token:`

Comment: Wouldn’t u be equal to just my email?

Comment: What are you trying to check here?  Are you trying to check whether the token matches a SPECIFIC email address, or are you trying to find out which user matches the given token?  You really haven't told us anything about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I’m trying to see if the session value in the nested dictionary is equal to the token.

Answer (score 0):

Could this work for you?

```
retval = None
for user in USERS:
    if user['session'] == token:
        print('found it!')
        retval = user
        break # no need to check all others
if not retval:
    print('not found')
    raise Exception('Invalid token')
```